# Progress Dialog is shown only after Thread terminates

Tags: java, android, multithreading, progressdialog, ui-thread

I'm trying to connect to a TCP/IP socket in a thread the moment my app is opened, and would like to show a progress dialog while connecting. The problem is that the thread is always executed before the progress dialog is shown, which means that it is shown only after the socket connection has actually happened (or failed).

```
public static boolean startConnection (Context c) {

    boolean[] ret = new boolean[1];

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Connecting...");
    progressDialog.show();

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                clientSocket = new Socket();
                clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT), 5000);
                ret[0] = true;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                ret[0] = false;
            }
            ((Activity)c).runOnUiThread(progressDialog::dismiss);
        }
    };

    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ret[0];

}
```

And I'm invoking `startConnection` in the `onStart()` method:

```
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    if (ConnectionHandler.startConnection(this)) {
        goToMainActivity();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

How can I make it so that the progress dialog is shown *before* the thread actually starts?

Answer (score 0):

`t.join();` waits on the UI main thread until second thread t finishes, that's the reason your code is blocking the UI thread and the dialog doesn't appear.

In addition you can't call `progressDialog.dismiss()`; on the t thread, all code that interacts with the UI must be called on the main thread, you can try tom call it using `runOnUIThread()` activity method

Comment: Unfortunately I must call `t.join()` or else I couldn't wait for the thread to set the boolean value I need to return. I actually tried to use `runOnUIThread()` but the problem still wasn't solved, the thread starts before the progress dialog is shown and the join call forces the UI thread to wait. I will edit the code in the question.

Comment: That can be done in other ways that do not block the UI for example using a ExecutorService and passing a listener that is called when the job is done. The UI thread should not be blocked, this freezes your app and is a bad experience for the user.